# Refresh data in Wicket DataView

Tags: wicket

I have DropDownChoice and DataView at my page. DataView should show data according to what item is selected in DropDownChoice. How can I achieve this?

Thanks to PropertyModel I can change text of label in a pretty simple way. Is there som way for DataView? Not really looking for ajax refresh. Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 3):

Your `DataView` uses a `DataProvider` to get the values to show. If you add the `DataView` (or its parent) to an `AjaxRequestTarget` it will refetch the values from the `DataProvider`. You just need to make sure that changing the selection in the `DropDownChoice` will update the `DataProvider`.

E.g.

```
dropDown.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("onchange") {

    @Override
    protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        dataProvider.setSelectedItem(dropDownModel.getObject());
        target.add(dataView); //o dataView's parent
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

```
MyDataProvider {

private SomeObject selectedItem;

@Override
public Iterator<? extends SomeOtherObject> iterator(long first, long count) { 
    return this.service.findAllForItem(this.selectedItem).iterator();
}

//+size + setter for selectedItem

}
```

Comment: Could you please help me with updating DataProvider? I don't see any method for it. Just have getDataProvider in DataView object, no setter.

Comment: You have to create the method in **your** DataProvider. The `setSelectedItem` in my example does not exist; you have to create it.

Comment: Don't forget the `size()` method!